# Terraform cannot connect via ssh to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform

I'm getting a ssh error that is not adding up when trying to apply a terraform plan:

> - ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm for key exchange; client offered: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org ecdh-sha2-nistp256 ecdh-sha2-nistp384 ecdh-sha2-nistp521 diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 diffie-hellman-group1-sha1], server offered: [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256]

The instance can be connected to manually with the ssh key specified without issues. Here is the terraform connection string:

```
connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "ed209"
    private_key = "${file("${var.aws_key_path}")}"
    timeout = "2m"
    agent = true
    host = "${var.use_public_ip  ? aws_instance.castiron.public_ip : aws_instance.castiron.private_ip}" 
}
```

The connection is set to connect privately via the same route that I use ssh to manually connect to. Any ideas on what to try?

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: Terraform v0.10.6

Answer (score 0):

The way to use variable in `file` function is wrong. Should be:

```
private_key = "${file(var.aws_key_path)}"
```

Comment: terraform uses go lib `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` which is not 100% compatible with `openssh`. Make sure you run with the same protocol, upgrade openssh version on clients, etc.